# Does Google offer an export of all the cities they have in Places API?

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-places

We are looking for a list of all Cities Google has in their DB so we can make a table in our's that matches in order to normalize our data with theirs, primarily make sure our city names match theirs so when a user fills in a city we can autocomplete and match to our local table.

Is there an export or a way to obtain a list?

Comment: No. they don't.

Comment: Do you know of a way to achieve the end goal of matching our city names with theirs?

IE. St Louis = Saint Louis

Comment: Do you really need to get all the city names? This would be very expensive in case.

Comment: All city names in the US, Mexico, Canada. So somewhere between 45k-100k city names should only run about $400 at the worst if I went by Googles Geocoding pricing.